# method cellForRowAtIndexPath not called from method shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am new to ios. I have a tableview and a textfield.

When editing the textfield I want to display a list of elements in tableview, based on the input in textfield

I have the following method:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *searchText = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];

    [self.mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

but the method cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called. why?
I did intitialize dataSource and delegate.

Comment: put a breakpoint in this method and check if mainTableView is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called if there is at least 1 cell to display and if the tableview is visible.
Seems that some requirements are missing.
Have you check if `numberOfRowsInSection` return something different than 0 ?

Comment: i found the issue:) . I didn t return the right value in numberOfRowsInSection. THANK YOU!

Comment: I don t see any elements in each of the cell. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Just check your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Are the elements in it null or not added as subviews ?